# LinkedIn Internal Server Error for page posts and timeline

Tags: linkedin-api

we are registered with LI for posting on timeline and company pages.

In recent past and present, we have been repeatedly facing the issue of 'Internal Server Error' with post success. And next day it disappears. the behavior of the API's is surprising.
 The error is exactly the same:

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Internal API server error",
  "requestId": "0083ZG77NP",
  "status": 500,
  "timestamp": 1521124204410
}
```

We follow https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages and are using `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/shares?format=json` to post into the comapany pages.

Also, haven't observed any new changes to API.
Someone please help me understand what's happening with LI or are we missing something?

Comment: Surprise. Its resolved on its own. Happens now and then. Hey LinkedIn team, how about a clue on whats happening?

Comment: I've also faced the same issue. Do you know how to resolve it
Error: LinkedIn::Errors::InformLinkedInError: LinkedIn had an internal error. Please let them know in the forum. (500): Internal Server Error